# Basic If statement struggles

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it so that when the user types in the number 4, it is supposed to say correct or wrong, but instead it automatically pops up with haha you're pretty bad even without the user typing anything in. I honestly don't know how to fix it.

```
print("Welcome to the maths skills testing machine!")
userinput = input("\nAre you ready to test your maths skills?")


if userinput=="yes":
    print("\nGreat!")
else:
    print("\nWell we're doing it anyway!")

print("\nLets start with something basic...")
print("\nWhat is 2+2?")

userinput

if userinput=="4":
    print("\nAhh that was way too easy...")
else:
    print("\nHaha you are pretty bad")
```

I expect it to wait for the user to write an answer and THEN tell them whether its right or wrong. I feel as though I need to be using a string since it's a number though? Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You're not requesting `input` again.  Should be `userinput = input("What is 2+2")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to request a new input again, and assign it's value to the `userinput` variable, otherwise you are using data that was already inputted, in this case "yes", so the answer would never be "4".

You need to change this line from:

```
print("\nWhat is 2+2?")
```

to:

```
userinput = input("\nWhat is 2+2?")
```

Full code:

```
print("Welcome to the maths skills testing machine!")
userinput = input("\nAre you ready to test your maths skills?")


if userinput=="yes":
    print("\nGreat!")
else:
    print("\nWell we're doing it anyway!")

print("\nLets start with something basic...")
userinput = input("\nWhat is 2+2?")

if userinput=="4":
    print("\nAhh that was way too easy...")
else:
    print("\nHaha you are pretty bad")
```

Good luck!

Comment: Whoa that's awesome! thanks for fixing it, i had no idea what i was doing wrong.